# parse error on input `if' in catch clause for readFile

Tags: haskell, exception

I'm trying handling an exception when I read a file but I'm receiving the message

> parse error on input `if'

```
readTxt = do
            {catch (read_file) fix_error;}
            where
                read_file = do
                {
                    f <- openFile "file.txt" ReadMode;
                    content <- hGetContents f;
                    putStrLn content;
                    hClose f;
                }   
                fix_error erro if = isDoesNotExistError erro
                    then do
                    {
                        putStr "Exception: file doesn't exists";
                        writeFile "file.txt" "First Line"
                    }
                else ioError erro
```

I read that when I have an `if` I need that the `then` and `else` clauses return the same type. I believe that I'm doing this, so I don't know why I'm receiving the error message

Comment: I think if and the equals sign should switch positions​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You swapped `=` and `if` in the definition of `fix_error`.

The syntax for a definition is:

```
name args = body
```

The syntax for an `if` expression is:

```
if condition then true_branch else false_branch
```

You simply need to combine these:

```
fix_error erro = if isDoesNotExistError erro
               ----
  then do
    putStr "Exception: file doesn't exist"
    ...
  else ioError erro
```

Or use a guard:

```
fix_error erro
  | isDoesNotExistError erro = do
    putStr "Exception: file doesn't exist"
    ...
  | otherwise = ioError erro
```

I’ve omitted the curly braces and semicolons, but you can include them if you prefer.